# Nativescript ClassNotFoundException: com.tns.NativeScriptActivity

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

Currently I am struggling with Nativescript Vue. At first it works just fine. But after installing some plugins it does not work anymore. I have attached the error message below.

There is something I have noticed in the error logs. When gradle builds a project that does not work anymore there is a difference during 'app:runSbg'. There it says 'system cannot find sbg-bindings.txt'. Despite that gradle continues and the app gets deployed to the phone (with a black error screen, see logs).

The ridiculous thing is that once it breaks like that it is not easy to restore the project to its previos state. When I checkout the last working commit and delete node_modules, platforms/android and hooks and rebuild the project it still displays the same error page. I could restore the project somehow by checking out a very old commit and slowly check out commits which were closer to the last working commit. This is really confusing.

One plugin in particular that is crashing my application is the nativescript dropdown plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-drop-down).

What is wrong here?

EDIT:
Just tried the dropdown plugin in a fresh build and it is working fine. When I was working on another project the same thing was hapening to me two times when I was trying to install different plugins. It seems almost random to me.

tns version info (already tried updating old version, did not help): 

`√ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
‼ Update available for component nativescript. Your current version is 5.0.0-2018-11-02-12528 and the latest available version is 5.0.0.
‼ Update available for component tns-core-modules. Your current version is 4.2.1 and the latest available version is 5.0.2.
‼ Update available for component tns-android. Your current version is 4.2.0 and the latest available version is 5.0.0.
‼ Update available for component tns-ios. Your current version is 4.2.0 and the latest available version is 5.0.0.`

package.json

```
{
  "name": "demo-form",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A native application built with NativeScript-Vue",
  "license": "MIT",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.demoform",
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "4.2.0"
    },
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "4.2.0"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@vue/devtools": "5.0.0-beta.3",
    "nativescript-drop-down": "^4.0.1",
    "nativescript-modal-datetimepicker": "^1.1.10",
    "nativescript-socket.io": "^0.9.0",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "^1.0.4",
    "nativescript-toast": "^1.4.6",
    "nativescript-vue": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-vue-devtools": "^1.0.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "babel-traverse": "6.26.0",
    "babel-types": "6.26.0",
    "babylon": "6.18.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.2",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "lazy": "1.0.11",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "next",
    "nativescript-vue-template-compiler": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-worker-loader": "~0.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.2",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.0",
    "vue-loader": "^15.2.6",
    "webpack": "^4.16.4",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "~2.13.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

Error log:

```
Searching for devices...
Executing before-watchPatterns hook from C:\Users\Lenovo G50-45\Desktop\2Archiv\form-example\hooks\before-watchPatterns\nativescript-dev-webpack.js
Executing before-watch hook from C:\Users\Lenovo G50-45\Desktop\2Archiv\form-example\hooks\before-watch\nativescript-dev-webpack.js
Running webpack for Android...
Bundling application for entryPath .\main.js...
File change detected. Starting incremental webpack compilation...

webpack is watching the files…

Hash: fcca84f749738c1b2158
Version: webpack 4.25.1
Time: 14426ms
Built at: 2018-11-08 20:59:25
                                                              Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
                                   App_Resources/Android/app.gradle  229 bytes          [emitted]  
                 App_Resources/Android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml   1.42 KiB          [emitted]  
    App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/background.png   5.34 KiB          [emitted]  
          App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png   6.79 KiB          [emitted]  
          App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/logo.png   8.74 KiB          [emitted]  
    App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-ldpi/background.png   1.57 KiB          [emitted]  
          App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png   2.58 KiB          [emitted]  
          App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-ldpi/logo.png    3.1 KiB          [emitted]  
    App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/background.png   2.17 KiB          [emitted]  
          App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png   3.35 KiB          [emitted]  
          App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/logo.png   3.58 KiB          [emitted]  
App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-nodpi/splash_screen.xml  304 bytes          [emitted]  
   App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/background.png   9.72 KiB          [emitted]  
         App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png   11.8 KiB          [emitted]  
         App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/logo.png     15 KiB          [emitted]  
  App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/background.png   15.3 KiB          [emitted]  
        App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/icon.png   14.3 KiB          [emitted]  
        App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/logo.png   19.9 KiB          [emitted]  
 App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/background.png   21.9 KiB          [emitted]  
       App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/icon.png     19 KiB          [emitted]  
       App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/logo.png   26.2 KiB          [emitted]  
           App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/values-v21/colors.xml  104 bytes          [emitted]  
          App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/values-v21/strings.xml  153 bytes          [emitted]  
           App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/values-v21/styles.xml  898 bytes          [emitted]  
               App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/values/colors.xml  244 bytes          [emitted]  
              App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/values/strings.xml  153 bytes          [emitted]  
               App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/values/styles.xml   1.68 KiB          [emitted]  
                                 assets/images/NativeScript-Vue.png   8.22 KiB          [emitted]  
                                                          bundle.js    101 KiB  bundle  [emitted]  bundle
                                                       package.json  134 bytes          [emitted]  
                                                         starter.js   39 bytes          [emitted]  
                                                tns-java-classes.js    0 bytes          [emitted]  
                                                          vendor.js   7.58 MiB  vendor  [emitted]  vendor
Entrypoint bundle = vendor.js bundle.js
[./ sync ^\.\/app\.(css|scss|less|sass)$] . sync nonrecursive ^\.\/app\.(css|scss|less|sass)$ 175 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./ sync recursive (root|page)\.(xml|css|js|ts|scss)$] . sync (root|page)\.(xml|css|js|ts|scss)$ 160 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app.scss] 18.7 KiB {bundle} [optional] [built]
[./main.js] 2.01 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./package.json] 118 bytes {bundle} [optional] [built]
[./utils/DateService.js] 651 bytes {bundle} [built]
    + 172 hidden modules
Webpack compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
Webpack build done!
Copying template files...
Platform android successfully added. v4.2.0
Executing before-shouldPrepare hook from C:\Users\Lenovo G50-45\Desktop\2Archiv\form-example\hooks\before-shouldPrepare\nativescript-dev-webpack.js
Preparing project...
Executing before-prepareJSApp hook from C:\Users\Lenovo G50-45\Desktop\2Archiv\form-example\hooks\before-prepareJSApp\nativescript-dev-webpack.js
Built aar for nativescript-socket.io
Project successfully prepared (Android)
Executing after-prepare hook from C:\Users\Lenovo G50-45\Desktop\2Archiv\form-example\hooks\after-prepare\nativescript-dev-webpack.js
Building project...
Gradle build...
     + setting applicationId
     + applying user-defined configuration from C:\Users\Lenovo G50-45\Desktop\2Archiv\form-example\app\App_Resources\Android\app.gradle
     + adding nativescript runtime package dependency: nativescript-optimized-with-inspector
     + adding aar plugin dependency: C:\Users\Lenovo G50-45\Desktop\2Archiv\form-example\node_modules\nativescript-socket.io\platforms\android\nativescript_socket.io.aar
     + adding aar plugin dependency: C:\Users\Lenovo G50-45\Desktop\2Archiv\form-example\node_modules\tns-core-modules-widgets\platforms\android\widgets-release.aar
   java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Lenovo G50-45\Desktop\2Archiv\form-example\platforms\android\build-tools\sbg-bindings.txt (Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
        at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.getRows(Generator.java:145)
        at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.generateBindings(Generator.java:85)
        at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.writeBindings(Generator.java:63)
        at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Main.main(Main.java:48)
Project successfully built.
Installing on device 23c8172f...
Successfully installed on device with identifier '23c8172f'.
Using  C:\Users\Lenovo G50-45\Desktop\2Archiv\form-example\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
device: 23c8172f debug port: 40000

# NativeScript Debugger started #
To start debugging, open the following URL in Chrome:
chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&ws=localhost:40000

Successfully synced application org.nativescript.application on device 23c8172f.
System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.tns.NativeScriptApplication: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
System.err: 
System.err: Error calling module function 
System.err: 
System.err: Error calling module function 
System.err: 
System.err: Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tns.NativeScriptActivity
System.err:     java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
System.err:     java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
System.err:     java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:378)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.getClassForName(Runtime.java:1036)
System.err:     com.tns.ClassResolver.resolveClass(ClassResolver.java:27)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.resolveClass(Runtime.java:604)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Native Method)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Runtime.java:553)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:545)
System.err:     com.tns.NativeScriptApplication.onCreate(NativeScriptApplication.java:21)
System.err:     android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5745)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1657)
System.err:     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
System.err:     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6499)
System.err:     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:440)
System.err:     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
System.err: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.tns.NativeScriptActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.nativescript.application-r-1DkV5Q5aCk9Ngfl87WVw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.nativescript.application-r-1DkV5Q5aCk9Ngfl87WVw==/lib/arm, /data/app/org.nativescript.application-r-1DkV5Q5aCk9Ngfl87WVw==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
System.err:     dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
System.err:     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
System.err:     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
System.err:     java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
System.err:     java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
System.err:     java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:378)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.getClassForName(Runtime.java:1036)
System.err:     com.tns.ClassResolver.resolveClass(ClassResolver.java:27)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.resolveClass(Runtime.java:604)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Native Method)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Runtime.java:553)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:545)
System.err:     com.tns.NativeScriptApplication.onCreate(NativeScriptApplication.java:21)
System.err:     android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5745)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1657)
System.err:     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
System.err:     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6499)
System.err:     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:440)
System.err:     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
System.err: File: "/data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/internal/ts_helpers.js, line: 128, column: 25
System.err: 
System.err: StackTrace: 
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/internal/ts_helpers.js', line: 128, column: 26
System.err:     Frame: function:'__decorate', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/internal/ts_helpers.js', line: 22, column: 19
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'', line: 69, column: 26
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'', line: 71, column: 2
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'', line: 72, column: 30
System.err:     Frame: function:'../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/activity.js', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/vendor.js', line: 586, column: 1
System.err:     Frame: function:'__webpack_require__', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/bundle.js', line: 76, column: 30
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'', line: 11, column: 1
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'', line: 41, column: 30
System.err:     Frame: function:'./main.js', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/bundle.js', line: 234, column: 1
System.err:     Frame: function:'__webpack_require__', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/bundle.js', line: 76, column: 30
System.err:     Frame: function:'checkDeferredModules', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/bundle.js', line: 45, column: 23
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/bundle.js', line: 149, column: 18
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/bundle.js', line: 152, column: 10
System.err:     Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/starter.js', line: 2, column: 1
System.err:     Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
System.err: 
System.err: 
System.err: Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tns.NativeScriptActivity
System.err:     java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
System.err:     java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
System.err:     java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:378)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.getClassForName(Runtime.java:1036)
System.err:     com.tns.ClassResolver.resolveClass(ClassResolver.java:27)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.resolveClass(Runtime.java:604)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Native Method)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Runtime.java:553)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:545)
System.err:     com.tns.NativeScriptApplication.onCreate(NativeScriptApplication.java:21)
System.err:     android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5745)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1657)
System.err:     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
System.err:     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6499)
System.err:     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:440)
System.err:     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
System.err: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.tns.NativeScriptActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.nativescript.application-r-1DkV5Q5aCk9Ngfl87WVw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.nativescript.application-r-1DkV5Q5aCk9Ngfl87WVw==/lib/arm, /data/app/org.nativescript.application-r-1DkV5Q5aCk9Ngfl87WVw==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
System.err:     dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
System.err:     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
System.err:     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
System.err:     java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
System.err:     java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
System.err:     java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:378)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.getClassForName(Runtime.java:1036)
System.err:     com.tns.ClassResolver.resolveClass(ClassResolver.java:27)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.resolveClass(Runtime.java:604)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Native Method)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Runtime.java:553)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:545)
System.err:     com.tns.NativeScriptApplication.onCreate(NativeScriptApplication.java:21)
System.err:     android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5745)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1657)
System.err:     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
System.err:     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6499)
System.err:     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:440)
System.err:     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
System.err: File: "<unknown>, line: 1, column: 265
System.err: 
System.err: StackTrace: 
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/internal/ts_helpers.js', line: 128, column: 26
System.err:     Frame: function:'__decorate', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/internal/ts_helpers.js', line: 22, column: 19
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'', line: 69, column: 26
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'', line: 71, column: 2
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'', line: 72, column: 30
System.err:     Frame: function:'../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/activity.js', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/vendor.js', line: 586, column: 1
System.err:     Frame: function:'__webpack_require__', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/bundle.js', line: 76, column: 30
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'', line: 11, column: 1
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'', line: 41, column: 30
System.err:     Frame: function:'./main.js', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/bundle.js', line: 234, column: 1
System.err:     Frame: function:'__webpack_require__', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/bundle.js', line: 76, column: 30
System.err:     Frame: function:'checkDeferredModules', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/bundle.js', line: 45, column: 23
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/bundle.js', line: 149, column: 18
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/bundle.js', line: 152, column: 10
System.err:     Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/starter.js', line: 2, column: 1
System.err:     Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
System.err: 
System.err: 
System.err: Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tns.NativeScriptActivity
System.err:     java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
System.err:     java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
System.err:     java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:378)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.getClassForName(Runtime.java:1036)
System.err:     com.tns.ClassResolver.resolveClass(ClassResolver.java:27)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.resolveClass(Runtime.java:604)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Native Method)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Runtime.java:553)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:545)
System.err:     com.tns.NativeScriptApplication.onCreate(NativeScriptApplication.java:21)
System.err:     android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5745)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1657)
System.err:     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
System.err:     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6499)
System.err:     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:440)
System.err:     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
System.err: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.tns.NativeScriptActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.nativescript.application-r-1DkV5Q5aCk9Ngfl87WVw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.nativescript.application-r-1DkV5Q5aCk9Ngfl87WVw==/lib/arm, /data/app/org.nativescript.application-r-1DkV5Q5aCk9Ngfl87WVw==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
System.err:     dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
System.err:     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
System.err:     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
System.err:     java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
System.err:     java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
System.err:     java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:378)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.getClassForName(Runtime.java:1036)
System.err:     com.tns.ClassResolver.resolveClass(ClassResolver.java:27)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.resolveClass(Runtime.java:604)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Native Method)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Runtime.java:553)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:545)
System.err:     com.tns.NativeScriptApplication.onCreate(NativeScriptApplication.java:21)
System.err:     android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5745)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1657)
System.err:     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
System.err:     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6499)
System.err:     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:440)
System.err:     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
System.err: File: "<unknown>, line: 1, column: 265
System.err: 
System.err: StackTrace: 
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/internal/ts_helpers.js', line: 128, column: 26
System.err:     Frame: function:'__decorate', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/internal/ts_helpers.js', line: 22, column: 19
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'', line: 69, column: 26
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'', line: 71, column: 2
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'', line: 72, column: 30
System.err:     Frame: function:'../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/activity.js', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/vendor.js', line: 586, column: 1
System.err:     Frame: function:'__webpack_require__', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/bundle.js', line: 76, column: 30
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'', line: 11, column: 1
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'', line: 41, column: 30
System.err:     Frame: function:'./main.js', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/bundle.js', line: 234, column: 1
System.err:     Frame: function:'__webpack_require__', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/bundle.js', line: 76, column: 30
System.err:     Frame: function:'checkDeferredModules', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/bundle.js', line: 45, column: 23
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/bundle.js', line: 149, column: 18
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/bundle.js', line: 152, column: 10
System.err:     Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/starter.js', line: 
...
```

Comment: It guess it may not be the dropdown plugin, are you using any plugins those which extend the default activity. For instance the NFC plugin internally creates it's own and you might have to update your manifest.

Comment: Yeah I tried the dropdown plugin in a fresh build and it worked there. In the project I was talking about I had these dependencies: I also used "nativescript-modal-datetimepicker", the rest were all pre-installed 

(Full List: 
`   
 "@vue/devtools": "5.0.0-beta.3",
    "nativescript-modal-datetimepicker": "^1.1.10",
    "nativescript-socket.io": "^0.9.0",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "^1.0.4",
    "nativescript-toast": "^1.4.6",
    "nativescript-vue": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-vue-devtools": "^1.0.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "^4.2.0",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
`

Comment: Are you using latest CLI or 4.2.0 only? Would you mind pasting the full `package.json`?

Comment: I am using the cli from https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/getting-started/quick-start/ . I have added `package.json` to the description.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I am experiencing the same issue

Comment: There are a few things I did, I don't know for sure if any of these changed anything but I haven't encountered any issues so far anymore.
First try to install stable nativescript and nativescript core modules. Before tns doctor showd something like `nativescript-core-modules: 5.0.2345`. After reinstalling I only had 5.x.x versions. I also installed the latest version of the cli (with the @next option). I also found out that when I changed `devtool: none` to devtool: `eval-source-map` the build did not work anymore for some reason. Every time I rebuild I had to set to `none` again.